# Unable to Parse Array from Returned JSON using Moshi

Tags: json, retrofit2, moshi

I've started using Moshi along with Retrofit 2 and have run into an issue parsing an array of objects within the parent object that is returned from the service call. The returned JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "acf": {
        "email": "dirk@dirkgently.com",
        "address": "24 Cortland Avenue",
        "country": "US",
        "description": "Oh my goodness",
        "created_at": "1416672067",
        "updated_at": "1416672067",
        "facebook": "",
        "contact": "Dirk Gently",      
        "photos": [
            {
                "file": 3525
            },
            {
                "file": 3526
            },
            {
                "file": 6110
            },
            {
                "file": 3527
            },
            {
                "file": 3528
            },
            {
                "file": 6700
            },
            {
                "file": 7404
            },
            {
                "file": 7419
            }
        ],

        "latitude": "40.801249",
        "longitude": "-99.746280"
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following exception with the 'photos' field:

> com.squareup.moshi.JsonDataException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was
>   STRING at path $[0].acf.photos

I've defined the models like so:

```
public class Acf {

private String email;
private String address;
List<Photo>photos;

}

public class Photo {
    public int file;
}
```

I've tried declaring the property in the model in various other ways, and read through the docs to try to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm stuck at this point and could really use a second set of eyes to point me in the right direction. I have a feeling I'm missing something painfully simple and obvious. Thanks in advance to anyone that can help. If I've left out any pertinent info let me know and I'll update the post.

**Update**: I've found that this exception only occurs when I fetch multiple ACFs. If I do a request for a single object everything parses correctly.

Comment: can you post all of your model classes that is Acf, Photo and MainRespose

Comment: Is there ever a JSON response that has a string value for `"photos"`?

Comment: @EricCochran Yes. It's peculiar that it will parse fine if I fetch the individual record by id, but it doesn't work for that field when I fetch multiples (paged). I'm going to dig into the documentation a bit deeper and see if there is a better way to log it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error it sounds like the endpoint you're calling is possibly returning different types for that parameter (i.e. a string when you're expecting an array). Try changing it from a List<> to an Object and see if the call succeeds. You should be able to type-check the Object and cast whatever you need from it. An alternative would be to use a custom type adapter, but I'm not sure how to accomplish that using Moshi. Good luck.

Comment: I am pretty sure I tried substituting a generic object for the array, but the past two days are a bit foggy. I'll give it a shot. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestion. It's not ideal, but it works great considering I can't change the endpoints.